# How to make a condition in where clause as void

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in Postgresql where we have a parameter uuid[]. I basically have 2 requirements.

1. uuid[] I would like to make it as optional
2. In the where clause if uuid[] is null or not passed then the condition I would like to make it as void something similar to COALESCE.

I tried the below function for my requirement . For setting it as optional I have set it as default null and in the where clause used COALESCE. However it throws error saying
syntax error at or near "ANY"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spgetuserinvitations(    
    p_useremail character varying,
    p_homeids uuid[] default null)
    RETURNS TABLE(invitationid uuid) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
#variable_conflict use_column

<<fnp>>
DECLARE
    v_exmsg VARCHAR(1000);  
BEGIN  
    
    RETURN QUERY
SELECT
  *
FROM table  
WHERE (useremail) = (p_useremail)
    AND invh.homeid = COALESCE(ANY(p_homeIds),invh.homeid)    

  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS fnp.v_errorstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
                        fnp.v_errormsg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
                    fnp.v_exmsg := COALESCE(fnp.v_errormsg, 'Unknown Error');
                    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error %, severity %, state % was raised. Message: %.', '50000', 14, -1, fnp.v_exmsg USING ERRCODE = fnp.v_errorstate;
END fnp;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Does this work for you?  `invh.homeid = any(coalesce(p_homeIds), array[invh.homeid])` ?

Comment: No , it says syntax error at or near ","

Comment: Does Any allow more than 1 parameter ?

Comment: Sorry.  Please try this:  `invh.homeid = any(coalesce(p_homeIds, array[invh.homeid]))`  That was a transcription error on my side.  Point is that both arguments to `coalesce()` must be the same type.  In this case, they have to both be arrays.

Comment: In this case: invh.homeid = any(coalesce(p_homeIds, array[invh.homeid])) , when the homeid is null the clause should become void which is not the case here .

Comment: Explain yourself better.  What do you mean by "void"?  Do you want to include or exclude records when `homeid` is null?

Comment: Exclude when homeid is null that means this clause is void as good as 1==1

Comment: I think the idea is that when you put 1=1 in the SQL, the database will optimise it away.

Comment: @amitagarwal What makes you say "*which is not the case here*"? Mike's suggestion should work

Comment: @Bergi If my understanding is right, Mike's suggestion [won't work](https://dbfiddle.uk/OUqH7Gc2). The misleading part is that OP points out to Mike that `invh.homeid` could be null, while the logic shown in the question would work only if `invh.homeid` is never null. If it couldn't be null, it can be safely used to collapse that condition to a `self==self`, `1==1`, `anynonnull=anynonnull`, skipping or "voiding" that whole line, which seems to be the goal here. If it can be null, neither OP's approach nor Mike's yields the desired result because of a possible `null=null` scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `p_homeIds` holds a list of identifiers that you normally want to filter down to, but if the function call skips `p_homeIds` entirely or passes a `null` there, you want to disable the filter: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lO6oF_2T)

```sql
WHERE (useremail) = (p_useremail)
AND (p_homeIds IS NULL OR invh.homeid=ANY(p_homeIds) );
```

If `invh.homeid` can be `null` and you want to be able to list `null` in `p_homeIds` and search for records that have `invh.homeid` set to `null`, then [`array_position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#id-1.5.8.25.6.2.2.8.1.1.1) might be a better choice:

```sql
WHERE (useremail) = (p_useremail)
AND (p_homeIds IS NULL OR array_position(p_homeIds,invh.homeid) IS NOT NULL);
```

That's because

- `null=any(array['a',null,'b'])` yields `null` because it uses `null=null` comparison
- `array_position(array['a',null,'b'], null)` yields `2` because it uses `null IS NOT DISTINCT FROM null` when checking the array elements

---

As to why this happened, the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) explains the expected syntax for `ANY`:

> *`expression`* *`operator`* `ANY` (*`array expression`*)

It has to be directly preceded by an *operator* which was missing in your case. A section earlier, there's also an [`ANY` with a subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME) instead of the array but it still expects to be directly preceded by an operator.

The idea suggested by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76980115/5298879) is valid, but again the syntax isn't: [`IN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) works with a subquery (where you could unnest an array), or with [a literal list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR), but not with a plain array expression directly.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```sql
AND (CASE WHEN p_homeIds IS NULL THEN true ELSE invh.homeid IN p_homeIds END)
```

Comment: Can I use this in where clause ? As this didn't work for me in where clause.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the COALESCE around the ANY(p_homeIds) and replace it with (p_homeids IS NULL OR invh.homeid = ANY(p_homeids)). This will make the filter "void" if p_homeids is NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spgetuserinvitations(    
p_useremail character varying,
p_homeids uuid[] default null)
RETURNS TABLE(invitationid uuid) 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
#variable_conflict use_column

<<fnp>>
DECLARE
    v_exmsg VARCHAR(1000);  
BEGIN  
    
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
      *
    FROM table  
    WHERE (useremail) = (p_useremail)
    AND (p_homeids IS NULL OR invh.homeid = ANY(p_homeids));

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS fnp.v_errorstate = RETURNED_SQLSTATE,
    fnp.v_errormsg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    fnp.v_exmsg := COALESCE(fnp.v_errormsg, 'Unknown Error');
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error %, severity %, state % was raised. Message: %.', '50000', 14, -1, fnp.v_exmsg USING ERRCODE = fnp.v_errorstate;

END fnp;
$BODY$;
```

Alternatively you could also use a Where clause variable to build and condition it similar to this:

```
DECLARE
cHomeIDsClause text;
BEGIN
    IF p_homeids IS NULL THEN
        cHomeIDsClause := ' AND 1 = 1';
    ELSE
        cHomeIDsClause := ' AND invh.homeid = ANY(p_homeids)';
    END IF;
    
    -- append cHomeIDsClause 
END;
```